# If the consecutive vertices $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4$ of a quadrilateral lie on a circle prove that...

Tags: complex-numbers, cross-ratio

If the consecutive vertices $z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4$ of a quadrilateral lie on a circle, prove that

$${|z_1-z_3|}\times{|z_2-z_4|}={|z_1-z_2|}\times{|z_3-z_4|}
+{|z_2-z_3|}\times{|z_1-z_4|}$$

This problem is given in L.V. Ahlfors text 'Complex Analysis: An introduction to the theory of analytic functions of one complex variable'

My Attempt:
By theorem,"The cross ratio $(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)$ is real if and only if the four points lie on a circle or on a straight line."

Let $(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)=r$ where $r$ is any real, from which I find that
$$(z_1-z_3)(z_2-z_4)=r(z_2-z_3)(z_1-z_4)$$
Also $(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)=s$ from which
$$(z_1-z_3)(z_2-z_4)=s(z_1-z_2)(z_3-z_4) $$
But, now I do not know how to find the values of $r$ and $s.$
Please help.

Comment: Umm, you're title seems to have a copy-and-paste error - it just starts all over again.

Comment: Lookup [Ptolemy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_theorem).

Comment: I have to show it using cross ratios

Comment: @tiwari_at183 Read that page more carefully.

Answer (score 2):

Tips:

$$(z_1-z_3)(z_2-z_4)=(z_1-z_2)(z_3-z_4)+(z_2-z_3)(z_1-z_4)$$